# Reusable bottom navigation bar state - Doesn't keep the state

Tags: flutter

I've created a bottom navigation bar and everytime I use it in different pages its state is back to first item. What am I missing? Thank you.

There are 5 routes defined in a list (and in the main.dart file), so everything is working good except the state.

I've tried with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin but I'm not sure that I've used it correctly (it's in the code below).

Here is the code:

```
class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  MyBottomNavigationBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyBottomNavigationBarState createState() => MyBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  int bottomTabIndex = 0;
  var routes = ['/', '/', '/my_categories', '/my_people_list', '/my_chat'];

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomTabIndex = index;
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, routes.elementAt(bottomTabIndex));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    theme:
    MyFirstTheme().theme;

    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      //
      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
      iconSize: 24,
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text(
            'HOME',
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
          title: Text(
            'STATS',
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.view_list),
          title: Text(
            'INVENTORY',
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.group),
          title: Text(
            'PEOPLE',
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.forum),
          title: Text(
            'CHAT',
          ),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: bottomTabIndex,
      onTap: onTabTapped,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code where you use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need PageStorage and PageStorageBucket 
If you define an widget for bottomNavigationBar, you need to pass page index
code snippet

```
final List<Widget> pages = [
    FirstPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),
    ),
    SecondPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('Page2'),
    ),
  ];
 ...
final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
  body: PageStorage(
    child: pages[_selectedIndex],
    bucket: bucket,
  ),
);
}
```

You can reference the detail https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1 
Github code https://github.com/lscardinali/FlutterBottomNavigationBarStatePersistanceSample

demo for github code, you can see page keep its state

[image]